# Cant type hebrew letters in TextEdit or any other edit field

Tags: android, hebrew

Cant type hebrew letters in TextEdit or any other edit field already tried every 
 edit field type, english or numbers are displayed fine except hebrew. I'm using Android Studio 3.1.2 API 15 Android Emulator 4.4.

Already tried:

1. Added strings.xml (iw-rIL) with hebrew support
2. Added tahoma font to assets folder
3. Created clean andriod project only with TextEdit field
4. Created on change event and its not fired on hebrew letters - on english letters, numbers and sybols event working fine.
5. If I set default text with hebrew letters i do see the hebrew text - but again cannot type.

In eclipse the hebrew letter working fine only have this problem in Android Studio

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you able to show soft keyboard in hebrew language?

Comment: I think the problem is in the emulator, cause now i've tried search with google (in emulator) the same problem occured hebrew letter not shown. I've unchecked Enable keyboard inpout and i dont see soft keyboard neither when is was checked.